# Data pivot with awk

Tags: awk, csv

I'm trying to pivot a file using awk. This is an example of my input File:

```
VarName;TimeString;VarValue;Validity;Time_ms
A;23.11.201215:03:53;1;1;41236627696,7593
C;23.11.201215:03:53;2;1;41236627696,7593
D;23.11.201215:03:53;3;1;41236627696,7593
A;23.11.201215:04:53;31;1;41236628391,2037
B;23.11.201215:04:53;12;1;41236628391,2037
C;23.11.201215:04:53;1;1;41236628391,2037
D;23.11.201215:05:53;8;1;41236629097,2222
B;23.11.201215:05:53;7;1;41236629097,2222
C;23.11.201215:05:53;15;1;41236629097,2222
```

And this is my desired output:

```
TimeString;Time_ms;A;B;C;D
23.11.201215:03:53;41236627696,7593;1;;2;3
23.11.201215:04:53;41236628391,2037;31;12;1;
23.11.201215:05:53;41236629097,2222;;7;15;8
```

Which is the best way to obtain this result?

Solved using the script writed by @steve

Comment: Could you explain what a data pivot is, for those of us who don't grok databases? Does it have to be awk — this may be easier to do in perl/python/ruby?

Comment: I'm new to programming... I performed my first data management with sed and now im looking to awk. I don't now if this may be easier to do in perl/python/ruby but I think that awk can do this. Any Help is usefull thank you

Comment: in `And this is my desired output:` 2nd line I see an `A` value of `31`.Where does this come from? How does that derive from your example? - sorry for the noise - I've got it

Comment: Please don't mark your question as "solved": this is a wiki, not a forum. Accept the correct answer so it is marked as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `gawk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=";"
}

NR==1 {
    r = $2 FS $5
    next
}

{
    !x[$1]
    a[$2,$5][$1]=$3
}

END {

    m = asorti(x,y)
    for (k=1;k<=m;k++) {
        r = r FS y[k]
    }
    print r

    n = asorti(a,b)
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        for (j=1;j<=m;j++) {
            for (k in a[b[i]]) {
                if (k == y[j]) {
                    var = a[b[i]][k]
                }
            }

            line = line FS var
            var = ""
        }
        sub(SUBSEP, FS, b[i])

        print b[i] line
        line = ""
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" } NR==1 { r = $2 FS $5; next } { !x[$1]; a[$2,$5][$1]=$3 } END { m = asorti(x,y); for (k=1;k<=m;k++) { r = r FS y[k] } print r; n = asorti(a,b); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) { for (j=1;j<=m;j++) { for (k in a[b[i]]) { if (k == y[j]) { var = a[b[i]][k] } } line = line FS var; var = "" } sub(SUBSEP, FS, b[i]); print b[i] line; line = "" } }' file
```

Results:

```
TimeString;Time_ms;A;B;C;D
23.11.201215:03:53;41236627696,7593;1;;2;3
23.11.201215:04:53;41236628391,2037;31;12;1;
23.11.201215:05:53;41236629097,2222;;7;15;8
```

---

---

You need to run `dos2unix` on your file first. i.e:

```
dos2unix Flussi0.csv
```

Alternatively, change the record separator to `\r\n` so that `awk` knows what a windows newline ending looks like. You can do this in the `BEGIN` block:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=";"
    RS="\r\n"
}
```

Results with the input file posted in the comments below:

```
"TimeString";"Time_ms";"FIT01";"FIT02";"FIT03";"FIT04";"FIT05";"FIT06"
"22.06.2012 09:31:33";41082396909,7222;1,157408E-02;5,787041E-03;2,507718E-02;2,89352E-03;2,314816E-02;5,787035E-04
"22.06.2012 09:32:34";41082397615,7407;1,157408E-02;5,787041E-03;2,314816E-02;2,89352E-03;2,713479E-02;5,787035E-04
"22.06.2012 09:33:35";41082398321,7593;1,157408E-02;5,787041E-03;2,314816E-02;2,89352E-03;2,314816E-02;5,787035E-04
"22.06.2012 09:34:35";41082399016,2037;1,157408E-02;5,787041E-03;2,314816E-02;2,89352E-03;2,535274E-02;5,787035E-04
"22.06.2012 09:35:36";41082399722,2222;;;;;2,314816E-02;
```

Comment: Perfect works Good!!!  Tank you a lot

Comment: The script fully work whit the example but I tried on an other file and fails. I tried whit a real file that I must edit whit this script... I don't know why but something goes wrong (unexpected line break after column 2)... What's the difference between my example and [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ejs6dnm6znxfhv/Flussi0.csv)? Did I something wrong? Here there is the [output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1x3epv2m06yebzo/ris.csv)

Comment: Update: script fails when numbers are present in this format: 1E-02

Comment: @Ludovico: There's nothing wrong with the script. You're just not using it correctly. Please see the update. HTH.

Comment: Thank you @steve I modified the awk script as you write. It's work very well. I hope this discussion will help other people

Comment: @Ludovico: No problem, I'm glad it's working for you. However to mark a question as being solved, you should click on the tick to the left of your favorite answer. Also, U&L (like all of the other SE sister sites) is a Q&A site, not some sort of forum - so there's no need to add the word 'solved' to the question's title. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The best way?  I don’t know.  Here’s *a* way. 
I assumed that the code didn’t really need to look at the header line of the input data, and could just hard-code `TimeString;Time_ms;`.

```
(line > /dev/null; sort) < input_file > tmp0    # Discard the header line; sort the data.
        # Here lies the basic pivot:
awk -F";" '
    {
        print $1 > "tmp1"
        print $2 > "tmp2"
        print $5 > "tmp5"
    }' tmp0
echo "TimeString;Time_ms;\c"
tr "\n" ";" < tmp1; echo
tr "\n" ";" < tmp2; echo
tr "\n" ";" < tmp5; echo
```

This will end each line of the output with a semicolon (`;`).  It wasn’t clear whether you wanted that.  If you don’t want it, you can probably figure out a way to eliminate it.

Comment: Thank you for your help... It's a good start but I should do it's a little bit different... My example was not so clear... I give you an other... I Modified original post. The semicolon at the end of the indicate the missing value (see the new example row two)

Comment: So, are you saying that you can handle it from here?  Or do you still need help?  I suggest that you work harder at making you question(s) understandable.  For example, TimeString and Time_ms go together –– couldn’t you have rearranged your input to put them in adjacent columns?  Also, ***every*** one of your TimeString values begins with `23.11.201215:0`, and ***every*** one of your Time_ms values begins with `4123662`.  This makes it very difficult for a person to look at the values and see which ones are the same and which ones are different.  I suggest that you remove the duplication.

Comment: You're right, I apologize

Answer (score 0):

Using the `reshape` sub-command of [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`, a CSV-aware tool), followed by `unsparsify`:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs ';' reshape -s VarName,VarValue then unsparsify file
TimeString;Validity;Time_ms;A;C;D;B
23.11.201215:03:53;1;41236627696,7593;1;2;3;
23.11.201215:04:53;1;41236628391,2037;31;1;;12
23.11.201215:05:53;1;41236629097,2222;;15;8;7
```

The `-s` option of the `reshape` sub-command takes a comma-delimited pair consisting of a key-field name and a value-field name.  It then does a long-to-wide pivot operation, creating the fields in the key field with the data from the value field.

The `unsparsify` operation is necessary to add the empty fields in the records that do not have all fields.

To also reorder the four last fields in the correct order and remove the `Validity` field:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs ';' reshape -s VarName,VarValue then unsparsify then reorder -e -f A,B,C,D then cut -x -f Validity file
TimeString;Time_ms;A;B;C;D
23.11.201215:03:53;41236627696,7593;1;;2;3
23.11.201215:04:53;41236628391,2037;31;12;1;
23.11.201215:05:53;41236629097,2222;;7;15;8
```

Or, shorter using only the `cut` sub-command for rearranging and selecting the output fields:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs ';' reshape -s VarName,VarValue then unsparsify then cut -o -f TimeString,Time_ms,A,B,C,D file
TimeString;Time_ms;A;B;C;D
23.11.201215:03:53;41236627696,7593;1;;2;3
23.11.201215:04:53;41236628391,2037;31;12;1;
23.11.201215:05:53;41236629097,2222;;7;15;8
```

In the general case, we may not know the names of the newly generated fields, so we may want to sort the fields by their names, remove the `Validity` field, and then put the two time fields first without mentioning the new fields by name:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --fs ';' reshape -s VarName,VarValue then unsparsify then sort-within-records then cut -x -f Validity then reorder -f TimeString,Time_ms file
TimeString;Time_ms;A;B;C;D
23.11.201215:03:53;41236627696,7593;1;;2;3
23.11.201215:04:53;41236628391,2037;31;12;1;
23.11.201215:05:53;41236629097,2222;;7;15;8
```